# How to install gmp4 on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos-catalina, gmp

I tried

```
brew install gmp@4
```

but it explained

```
No available formula with the name "gmp4"
```

I have gmp6 on macOS Catalina but I need gmp4 for some reasons, so how to install gmp4 on macOS Catalina?

Comment: Go find the sources on the [GMP website](https://gmplib.org/download/gmp/archive/) and build it from source following the instructions? You may be better off removing the reasons why you need "gmp4" though...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Download gmp-4.3.2](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gmp/gmp-4.3.2.tar.gz)

Extract the file and enter the directory.

```
CFLAGS="-O3 -w -pipe -arch x86_64"
CXXFLAGS="-O3 -w -pipe -arch x86_64"
LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gmp/4.3.2 --enable-cxx --build=x86_64-apple-darwin
make
make install
```

It will install gmp-4.3.2 in /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/4.3.2, enjoy!